# Selecting range to apply borders - Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Here is what I need to do. Select a range of cells based on the row and column numbers. Since it is a dynamic one, I have to use the row and column numbers. I have hardcoded them here as an example. Once I have the range, I need to apply a thick border all around it. I am uable to select the range. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included part of the selection code. I have indicated where it fails.

```
Sub setBorder()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws  As Object
Dim rng      As Object
Dim startRow         As Integer, startCol As Integer
Dim endRow           As Integer, endCol As Integer

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\Documents\Misc-Work\BU\test.xlsx")

startRow = 6
startCol = 5
endRow = 15
endCol = 5

Set ws = wb.worksheets(1)

With ws
   Set rng = .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
   rng.select -- It fails here
End With

'rng.select

With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  no need to use select:

```
With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
End With

With rng.Borders(7)
    .LineStyle = 1
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = 2
End With
With rng.Borders(8)
    .LineStyle = 1
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = 2
End With
```

Btw, **Access don't know about constants** `xlEdgeLeft` and etc, until you add reference to *Microsoft Excel Object Library* in *Tools->References*. You can also change this constanst to their actual values without adding reference to library as in my code above, but this will make your code less clear.

Comment: I get an application-defined or object-defined error on           With rng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
Do you see anything wrong with my variable definitions?

Comment: try now..access don't know about constants `xlEdgeLeft` and etc, until you add reference to `microsoft excel object library` in _tools->references_. But you can change this constanst to their values as in my updated answer without adding reference to library