# Range issue in Access/excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Unsure what I am doing wrong. None of the statements below generate an error but yet they don't work. I had a question earlier about borders and I thought it worked but it didn't

Here is the code snippet

```
With ws
   With .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
      .Borders.LineStyle = 1
      .Borders.Weight = 4
   End With
End With

ws.Range("D1").Value = 3.14159

With ws.Range("D1").Borders(9)
    .LineStyle = 1
    .Weight = 2
    .ColorIndex = 3
End With

ws.usedrange.Borders.LineStyle = 1
ws.usedrange.Borders.Weight = 4
ws.usedrange.Borders.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

With ws.Range("E1:F2")
    .Value = "x"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Borders.LineStyle = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558366/selecting-range-to-apply-borders-access-vba)
and added last four lines for saving changes and closing wb. This should fix your issue:

```
Sub setBorder()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim ws As Object
    Dim rng As Object
    Dim startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer
    Dim endRow As Integer, endCol As Integer

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\Documents\Misc-Work\BU\test.xlsx")

    'your code

    wb.Close True
    xlApp.Quit
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note, since you've already run your previous code (without closing wb and xlApp), probably you need to close your file "H:\Documents\Misc-Work\BU\test.xlsx" using task manager (even if it's seems that you haven't this file opened)

Comment: Thanks simoco. I do have that in this as well. I did not add that to the question. The only thing missing was the xlApp.Quit. I added that but still doesnt work. I do have the MS excel library added. Not sure if there is anything else as far as the setting go.

Comment: try to close your workbook using task manager and then run code again. I've tested it using access and it works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Might be your parameters.............the following works:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    startRow = 3
    startCol = 3
    endRow = 7
    endCol = 7
    With ws
       With .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
          .Borders.LineStyle = 1
          .Borders.Weight = 4
       End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: let me try it out. my parameters were ok. I checked them right before this was invoked

Comment: Seems to work ok from within Excel. have Issues when I try it from inside access. Any ideas?